# Prove $f(y) = \min \{|y-x|, x\in S\}$ is convex when $S = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^2|ax_1 + bx_2 = c\}$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $S$ be a convex non empty set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let
>   $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
>
> $$f(y) = \min \{|y-x|, x\in S\}$$
>
> This function is convex. Prove this affirmation when
>
> $$S = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^2|ax_1 + bx_2 = c\}$$
>
> Interpret geometrically

So $f$ at $y$ is simply the point of the line $ax_1+bx_2=c$ which is the closest to $y$. Normally I'd write the convex function definition and try to look at it to see some relation:

$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$$

so I'd have to come up with something like this:

$$\min\{|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y-z|, z\in S\}\le \lambda \min\{|x-z|, z\in S\} + (1-\lambda)\min\{|y-z|, z\in S\}$$

I tried using the triangular inequation:

$$|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y-z|\le \lambda|x|+(1-\lambda)|y|+|z|$$

but I don't think anything useful comes from this.

Comment: Note that if $$g(x,y)=\begin{cases} \|x-y\| & x\in S \\ +\infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$Then $f(y)=\inf_x g(x,y)$. It is known that partial minimization of convex functions is convex. If you're able to use that fact, and the extended real convention, you've got this in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\min$ should be an $\inf$ since a minimiser need not exist.

Let $d_S(x) = \inf_{s \in S} |s-x|$, note that it is the distance from $x$ to the set
$S$ (or rather its closure).

Let $\epsilon>0$. Pick $x_k$ ($k=1,2$) and then select $s_k \in S$ such that
$|x_k-s_k| \le d_S(x_k) +\epsilon$. Then, with $t \in [0,1]$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
d_S(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) &\le& |tx_1+(1-t)x_2 - (ts_1+(1-t)s_2)| \\
&\le& t|x_1-s_1|+(1-t)|x_2-s_2| \\
&\le& t d_S(x_1) + (1-t) d_S(x_2) + \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
Since this is true for all $\epsilon>0$ we have the desired result.

Note that convexity of $S$ is needed above to conclude that $ts_1+(1-t)s_2 \in S$.

This is a very useful function in convex and non differentiable analysis.

Comment: Under the assumption that $S$ is non-empty, and given that the function is bounded below, it seems to me the minimum must indeed exist.

Comment: If you take $ S= (1,2)$, then $d_S(0) = 1$, but there is no point in $S$ that minimises the distance. A technicality, but then I am a pedant :-).

Comment: Do you mean $S=\{1,2\}$? That's not convex, right?

Comment: The open interval $(1,2)$.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks! To be clear I'm all for technicalities! I was just wrong about this one!

Comment: The distance function is very (academically) useful for defining tangents and normals in the non differentiable world. Provides a nice (if detail rich) connect between the geometric & analytical worlds, always a source of fascination for me.

Comment: could you elaborate more on why $d(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le |tx_1+(1-t)x_2-(ts_1+(1-t)s_2)|$?

Comment: That is by definition of $d_S$.